# Retrieve Selected Drop down List value in Action method

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a hard coded drop down list I want to get the selected value in an action method on clicking on a button.

View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("GetSelectedValue","Home"))
{ 
    @Html.DropDownList("Departments", new List<SelectListItem>
    { 
    new SelectListItem { Text = "IT", Value = "1", Selected=true},
    new SelectListItem { Text = "HR", Value = "2"},
    new SelectListItem { Text = "Payroll", Value = "3"}
    }, "Select Department") 
    <button type="submit">next</button>
}
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult GetSelectedValue()
{
    string value = drop down value;
    //I tried this didnt work
    string selvalue = Request["Departments"];
    return View();
}
```

I do not want to include model or any View Models in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `FormCollection` parameter to your action method and get the selected value as below

```
public ActionResult GetSelectedValue(FormCollection form)
{
    string selectedValue = form["Departments"];
    return View();
}
```

Comment: I tried this but it gives me a error Server not found and the URL is http://localhost:5909/Home/GetValue  As its MVC 5 I gave the attribute routing as [Route("GetValue/{form:string}")] then too its not working my button is <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("GetValue", "Home")'" />

Comment: Why are you using `onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("GetValue", "Home")'"`? There's no need to do that if the submit button is inside `@Html.BeginForm()`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try simply adding it as a parameter on your Action, for example like:

```csharp
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetSelectedValue(string Departments)
{
    // do you stuff here
    return View();
}
```

Depending on your RouteConfig, this may just work out of the box.